# How can I duplicate a field?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with two fields, and i need to duplicate one field in another one with different name but same data

is it possible via phpmyadmin or so?

assuming i have

```
user_id |  user_name
```

i need to have

```
user_id |  user_name | user_name2
```

where user_name has same data as user_name2

what is the fastest way?
is just for some experiment purpose so dont comment on why i'm doing it
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update table_name set user_name2= user_name
```